# Syslog download into Atom

Tags: syslog, atom

I am looking for a way to download syslog from my ubuntu machine into atom. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little what you mean by "download"? Are you trying to open a syslog file remotely (from another computer) or are you just trying to open a local syslog file using the atom editor?

Comment: Hi there. I am trying to open up a local syslog file using the atom editor. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks - so what exactly is the issue you are facing? It should be no different from opening it in any other editor (either `atom /var/log/syslog` from the command line, or navigating to /var/log/syslog from the file open menu). Note that your user should normally be a member of the `adm` group in order to read syslog files.